# How to wrap a H264 stream to a MP4 container

Tags: video, streaming-video, opencv, raspivid, cvlc

I have successfully streamed an h264 video over the local network with this command.

```
raspivid -o - -t 0 -n -w 1280 -h 720  -vf -vs -fps 30  -b 3500000 | cvlc -vvv stream:///dev/stdin --sout '#rtp{sdp=rtsp://:8554/}' :demux=h264
```

I can view the stream on my iOS VLC app through the address

```
rtsp://192.168.0.146:8554/
```

But I have no luck viewing the stream on my local computer. Here's a script I made.

```py
import cv2
import imutils
from imutils.video import VideoStream

stream = "rtsp://192.168.0.146:8554/"

vs = VideoStream(src=stream).start()

while True:
    frame = vs.read()

    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) != -1:
        break
vs.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

OpenCV is not able to get any frame from the address. Please correct me if I'm wrong, but I am wondering perhaps it needs the video to be wrapped in a container like `mp4`. Can anyone tell me how to achieve that? Can it be easily piped in the first command?